# Insert a form in a jquery tab to submit data in database using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am using a form to submit data in three different tables, it is actually is a simple form with one submit button.

But now I want the form to be divided in three different tabs each having a button, when the page is loaded first tab should be opened with a form having personal details with a proceed button on clicking proceed button second tab should open up containing another part of form and same goes to final tab having a submit button.

I am not getting it how can it be done with php and JQuery tab.

this was the code i wrote

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function OtherWork(val){
   var element=document.getElementById('wtype');
      if(val=='other')
  element.style.display='block';
   else  
   element.style.display='none';
       }

</script> 

  <h2>Add New Entry</h2>
   <hr />
   <form action="processnewentry.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
  <table width="560" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
     <tr>
     <td width="234">Lead Name :</td>
     <td width="311"><input type="text" name="lename" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td width="234">Lead Date : (mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
       <td width="311"><input type="text" name="ldate" class="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="234">Contact Person :</td>
     <td width="311"><input type="text" name="conper"  /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="234">Company Name :</td>
    <td width="311"><input type="text" name="cname"  /></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td width="234">Mobile No. :</td>
    <td width="311"><input type="text" name="mobno"  /></td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="234">Landline No. :</td>
   <td width="311"><input type="text" name="phone"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="234">Address :</td>
    <td width="311"><textarea name="address" ></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="234">Email :</td>
    <td width="311"><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td width="234">Alt Address :</td>
   <td width="311"><textarea name="altaddress" ></textarea></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td width="234">Work Type :</td>
    <td width="311"><select name="wtype" onchange='OtherWork(this.value);'>
    <option value="Website Designing">Website Designing</option>
   <option value="Android Application">Android Application</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="text" name="wtype" id="wtype" style='display:none;'/>
    </td>

  </select>

       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td width="234">Work Description :</td>
          <td width="311"><textarea name="wdesc" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
         <td width="234">Expected Budget :</td>
          <td width="311"><input type="text" name="exbudget"  /></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
          <td width="234">Lead Executive :</td>
           <td width="311"><select name="lexec">
            <?php
     $q=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM $table');
   while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($q))
       {
  $na=$rr['name'];
?>
       <option value="<?php echo $na;?>"><?php echo strtoupper($na);?></option>
   <?php } ?>
    </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td width="234">Lead Manager :</td>
        <td width="311"><select name="lmana">
       <?php
 $q=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM $table');
while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$na=$rr['name'];
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $na;?>"><?php echo strtoupper($na);?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="234">Closing Date : (mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
    <td width="311"><input type="text" name="cldate" class="datepicker" /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="234">Lead Status :</td>
    <td width="311"><select name="lstat">
     <option value="Hot">Hot</option>
     <option value="Warm">Warm</option>
     <option value="Cold">Cold</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="234">Follow Up :</td>
    <td width="311"><textarea name="followup" ></textarea></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="234">Next Follow up : (mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
    <td width="311"><input type="text" name="nfoldate" class="datepicker" /></td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
   <td width="234">Remark if any :</td>
    <td width="311"><textarea name="remark" ></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="234">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="311"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  class="buttton" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
      </form>
```

Comment: do u have some code mate..??

Answer (score 0):

your form is having 3 parts(i.ir 3 different tabs).So give 3 different html classes to its fields.Eg. 
fields on first tab will look like : 
fields on first tab will look like : 
fields on first tab will look like :

At first, fields on second and third tab would be display none.

Now on click of first proceed button, validate fields(if required) and then, make fields on first tab display none using jquery(i.e. add css property)
Eg.

```
$("#first_proceed").click(function(){
   $(".first").css("display","none");
})
```

Same for second proceed button.
And on click of third button(i.e. submit), Submit your form